# Character 'e' is not recognized by simple regular expression - why?

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote a very simple regular expression that need to match the next pattern:
`word.otherWord`
- Word must have at least 2 characters and must not start with digit.

I wrote the next expression:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z](.[a-zA-Z0-9])+
```

I tested it using Regex tester and it seems to be working at most of the cases but when I try some inputs that ends with 'e' it's not working.

for example:
`Hardware.Make` does not work but `Hardware.Makee` is works fine, why? How can I fix it?

[image: See the tester results]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your regex looks for inputs which length is even.

You have two characters matched by `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]` and then another two characters matched by `(.[a-zA-Z0-9])` as a group which is repeated one or more times (because of `+`).

You can see it here: http://regex101.com/r/fW2bC1

I think you need that:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+
```

Comment: In addition to the even length problem, should the `.` be escaped, as the pattern should contain a verbatim `.`, not a wildcard character.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the dot is a regex metacharacter, which stands for "any character". You'll need to escape the dot.

For your situation, I'd do this:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

The `{2,}` means, at least 2 characters from the previous range.

Answer (score 1):

In regex, the dot period is one of the most commonly used metacharacters and unfortunately also commonly misused metacharacter. The dot matches a single character without caring what that character is...
So u would also re-write it like 
`[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+`